# How to add basic HTTP authentication for all Django pages?

Tags: python, django, basic-authentication

I am running a Django application using its built-in web server and I would like it to only serve the website after a successful authentication using the predefined login and password. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is this for tests? If not, you should not use the built-in server. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port

Comment: Uh, I don't know of a way for the entire app to require authentication, but putting the decorator @login_required on all of your views should do it? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

Comment: The built-in web server is only intended for development purposes.  If you are wanting a production-quality web server itself to generate a login prompt, such as Apache's basic HTTP authentication, you need to provide more information about what you need.